# talend tsendmail how to filter files with regex?

Tags: file, talend

I want to send email to specific persons that are in charge of 1 product each so i want to send an email having all related product files from same directory to each of those persons. All i could do is to iterate through files in a repository using filter but all i did is **filter** of extension .csv or .txt for example but that means all files will be sent to each person . any help please on using **regex filter** in tsendmail component ?? or a way to pass those filtered files in tsendmail , means how to send list of files to **tsendmail** like we do with list of emails ?

Comment: give some filename examples that you want to filter.

Comment: files are like" Productname_date.csv"  i want to say like  loop on those files , 
*if product1 send file with name "product1_TODAY.csv" to email : product1incharge@x.com
*if product2 send file with name "product2_TODAY.csv" to email : product2incharge@x.com

but i cannot say that in tsendmail component , so i need to iterate with some way that i don't know how  ,on those files and send each time a file  to an email that it correspands , let's assume i have Tflexfix that has list of 1 email for each product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is not needed here, you can do it with a simple tMap.

[image]

tFileList with `*_*.csv`  as Filemask

[image]

Use a tIterateToFlow to process the tFileList output. Create a schema with 3 columns. The product column contains the product name extracted from the filename :  `((String)globalMap.get("tFileList_1_CURRENT_FILE")).split("_")[0] )`

[image]

A tMap to join the product with the email to be used. A tFixedFlowInput is used to map the product to an email (a file will be better so you can add/remove product/email without rebuilding).

[image]

[image]

Finally the tSendMail is using the flow from tMap to send the mail with the processed file as attachment.
[image]

Comment: thank you a lot a great idea to follow, i will try it and it should work fine .

Answer (score 0):

here is an idea that may work ,from the beginning make dynamic file names in a temp directory than get those dynamic files with tfile and send each to their person .

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include some code example of solution. See [answer].